# Exim getting random credential in exim.conf

Tags: perl, exim, exim4

I have been trying to get perl subroutine value and substitution to get the required part of string from randomips subroutine in exim.conf. However when i use string substitution i get error as follow:

[Here is what I am trying to achieve](http://reqad.com/how-to-send-mail-from-multiple-ips-in-exim.html)

I am trying to split string by colon and get first occurrence as "interface". I'll be using second occurrence as the "helo_data.

exim.pl

```
sub randomhosts {
@inet = ("x.x.x.1:hostname1.domain.com","x.x.x.2:hostname2.domain.com","x.x.x.3:hostname3.domain.com"
);

return $inet[int rand($#inet+1)];

}
```

exim.conf

```
dkim_remote_smtp:
  driver = smtp
  interface = "${perl{randomhosts}%:*}"
  helo_data = "${sender_address_domain}"
```

Error I get is as follow:

`"failed to expand "interface" option for dkim_remote_smtp transport: missing '}' after 'perl'".`
Probably the syntax. 
Any help?

Comment: It seems to me you have a config file and are trying to just type perl commands in there hoping to get some result I am not sure of. Please clean up the question to make clear what you actually want. If you want to use perl to do something please post a usable piece of code or at least enough to have a chance at guessing what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have edited it. I dont know what more i can explain. Basically I am trying to rotate customs ips along with their respective custom host names in exim which is built with perl

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your question. Some of your code is being formatted as plain text. If you want us to look at your code, it is polite to make it as easy to understand as possible. Also, your definition of `@inet` seems to be missing a few quote characters - meaning that the code as it stands doesn't even compile. If you don't care enough to give us an accurate copy of your code, then why would we care enough to help you?

Comment: `$#inet+1` is better written as `@inet`. And in this case you don't even need `int`: `return $inet[rand @inet];`

Comment: What does this have to do with bash at all? You can't use bash expansions in perl code any more than you could put Python syntax in C.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Pedantically, he was trying to use bash expansions in Exim configuration code, not Perl code. Still doesn't work though :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that you are trying to copy was written by someone who doesn't know much about Perl. It includes this line:

```
return $inet[int rand($#inet+1)];
```

A Perl programmer would write this as

```
return $inet[rand @inet];
```

I think there are a couple of issues here - one with your Exim syntax and one with your Perl syntax.

Exim is giving you this error:

> failed to expand "interface" option for dkim_remote_smtp transport: missing '}' after 'perl'

I don't know anything about calling Perl from Exim, but [this page](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-embedded_perl.html) mentions a syntax like `${perl{foo}}` (which is similar to the one used in the page you are copying from) and one like `${perl{foo}{argument}}` for calling a subroutine and passing it an argument. Nowhere does it mention syntax like yours:

```
${perl{randomhosts}%:*}
```

I'm not sure where you have got that syntax from, but it seems likely that this is what is causing your first error.

In a comment, you say

> I am stying to get first part of string before colon for each random array value for "interface" and part after colon for "helo_data"

It seems to me that Exim doesn't support this requirement. You would need to call the function twice to get the two pieces of information that you require. You might be able to do this in the Perl using something like `state` variables - but it would be far more complex than the code you currently have there.

Secondly, your Perl code has a syntax error, so even if Exim was able to call your code, it wouldn't work.

The code you're copying sets up `@inet` like this:

```
@inet = ("x.x.x.1", "x.x.x.2", "x.x.x.3", "x.x.x.4");
```

Your equivalent code is this:

```
@inet = (
  "x.x.x.1:hostname1.domain.com",
  "x.x.x.2:hostname2.domain.com,
  x.x.x.3:hostname3.domain.com
 );
```

I've reformatted it, to make the problems more obvious. You are missing a number of quote marks around the elements of the array. (**Note:** I see that while I have been writing this answer, you have fixed that.)

**Update:** Ok, here is some code to put into `exim.pl` that does what you want.

```
use feature qw[state];

sub randomhosts {
  state $current;

  my @inet = (
    "x.x.x.1:hostname1.domain.com",
    "x.x.x.2:hostname2.domain.com",
    "x.x.x.3:hostname3.domain.com"
  );

  if ($_[0] eq 'generate') {
    shift;
    @{$current}{qw[ip host]} = split /:/, $inet[rand @inet];
  }

  return $current->{$_[0]};
}
```

It generates a new ip/host pair if its first argument is 'generate'. It will then return either the hostname or the ip address from the generated pair. I think you can probably call it from your Exim config file like this:

```
dkim_remote_smtp:
  driver = smtp
  interface = "${perl{randomhosts}{generate}{ip}}"
  helo_data = "${perl{randomhosts}{host}}"
```

But I'm no expert in Exim, so that syntax might need tweaking.

Comment: Thanks for your help Dave. However, this exim syntax was the problem. The method you introduced here does achieve what I was trying to get. Thanks again..

Comment: @Motsim: I'm glad it's useful. I hope you have taken the time understand how it works rather than just copying and pasting it. Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

First I would like to note I have not worked with exim so I cannot say what exactly you are trying to do and why you have done things exactly so.

In the link you posted, a method called 'randinet' is added to exim.pl and the interface line in exim.conf is replaced by

`interface = "${perl{randinet}}"`

You have implemented a 'randomhosts' method and replaced the interface line with

`interface = "${perl{randomhosts}%:*}"`

Now the parser complains about not finding the closing bracket. That is likely due to the symbols you felt free to add but the parser does not have the freedom to ignore.

I suggest you try

`interface = "${perl{randomhosts}}"`

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. I am trying to get first part of string before colon for each random array value for "interface" and part after colon for "helo_data" . Therefore, cannot use only `"${perl{randomhosts}}".